# Weighted median calculation in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to calculate weighted median in an aggregating query in Postgresql. 
How to do it efficiently (ideally using user-defined function written in C)?

Comment: What does `ideally using some C++ code as pglsh code` mean?

Comment: @eurotrash sorry, I mean a user-defined function written in C